std::numeric_limits<double>::min() - на самом деле не совсем min (и это не про отрицательные значения)
Удивило что код:
log_file << "\n" << std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
log_file << "\n" << std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
double test = 1e-10;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    test *= 1e-10;
log_file << "\n" << test;

Выдаёт результат:
1.79769e+308
2.22507e-308
9.99989e-321

Т.е. double test может хранить значение заметно меньше чем std::numeric_limits<double>::min().
И только если цикл до i < 32; то test выводится как ноль.
Аналогичный тест с умножением на 1e10 показывает что с ::max() всё в порядке и при превышении e+308 testстановится inf.
Есть версии почему так?

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::min() << '\n';        // 2.22507e-308
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min() << '\n'; // 4.94066e-324

min() выдает самое маленькое по модулю не-денормализованное число. Денормализованные могут быть меньше. Минимальное число с учетом денормализованных - denorm_min().
